# JavaScript MISBEHAVING -> CROSS ORIGIN RESOURCE EXCEPTION

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After long research and debugging i realized java-script was not the problem, I was rather having a `cross origin resource exception` which was thrown because some how the ajax request could not read my server script or rather did not have permission to access my server script. 
So i tried the following codes below but still the same issue, I placed the issue in red block blow, my java script is also below and my server script

```js
$('#send').on('click', function(e) {
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var message = $('#message').val();
  alert("sending " + name + email + message);// this part is now working fine
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://xxxxxx/xxxxx/php/contact/maincontact.php",
    data: {
      nme: name,
      ema: email,
      msg: message
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 10000,
    async: true,
    cache: true,// I removed the header which used to here before
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("error : " + errorThrown + " text :" + textStatus + " j :" + jqXHR.status);
      alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    success: Succeeded
  });

});


function Succeeded(result) {
  alert("Successing");
  var data = JSON.parse(result[0]);
  try {
    $('#name').val(" ");
    $('#email').val(" ");
    $('#message').val(" ");
    if (data == true) {
      alert("We will Contact you shortly");
    } else {
      alert("OOpps! something went wrong");
    }

  } catch (e) {
    alert("You may not enter " + e);
  }
}
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/php/contact/maincontact.php. (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-origin' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

```
<!-- php codes -->
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
require_once('contact.php');

if(!empty($_POST)){

    $addcase = new contact();
    $data['vlu'] = $addcase->add($_POST['nme'], $_POST['ema'],     $_POST['msg']);
    echo json_encode($data);

}else{
   echo "Not properly parsed";
}


?>
```

Comment: A bit of a clue as to what it is _not doing_ or what _it is doing wrong_ would help

Comment: @RiggsFolly signature of successHandler for ajax is `function(response){}`, so `Succeeded` should work. I don't think that is the issue. I guess we should wait until OP specifies **what is not working**.

Comment: I'ld recommend you ensure all scripts are correctly linked and also try clearing the erroneous browser's cache...

Comment: Few points to debug. Put a `console.log` in `$('#send').on('click'`. Second, in dev tools, in network tab, check your request. What data/headers its sending and what is the output.

Comment: I even downloaded a new web browser to test it. but same results. i have put the issues I am having up there.

Comment: If you set dataType as json you don't need to parse the response, you probably get error when you do so. Also in php you should return JSON on error as well `echo json_encode(array("error" => "Not properly parsed"));`

Comment: I fixed a similar problem by allowing access at the htaccess level. On the server that serves the PHP file through Ajax add:'<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(yyy.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> missing token 'access-control-allow-origin' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel

So when you make the **request** you are trying to put `access-control-allow-origin` in the headers. (The message means that browser is asking the server if it is allowed to send that header in cross-origin Ajax and the server isn't saying that it is OK to do that).

This doesn't make any sense. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a **response** header. There is no reason to put it on the request.

Now, the code you've provided **doesn't** try to set that header. This suggests that *elsewhere* in your code you are trying to set it universally (probably via [ajaxsetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)).

You need to find the point where you try to set it and remove that code.

Comment: Apparently I had not committed the change to the open-shift hosting server, I removed the `header` in my `ajax setup` as you said and it worked. Thanks.